# Can't run remote GNU Parallel jobs for files in a directory (directory not found)

Tags: gnu-parallel

Having a problem where unable to run remote GNU Parallel jobs for a `parallel` command that runs jobs on a cluster of nodes when the varying arg is based on a list of files in a directory output by a glob pattern.

The command look like

```sh
bcpexport() {
    <do some stuff to the given file arg $1 to BCP copy file contents to some MSSQL Server>
}
export -f bcpexport
parallel -q -j 10 --sshloginfile /path/to/list/of/nodes.txt --env $bcpexport \
    bcpexport {} "$TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN" $DB $TABLE $USER $PASSWORD $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE $DELIMITER \
    ::: "$DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB"
```

When run on a single node, things work fine; the `"$DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB"` glob pattern has the form `/path/to/a/set/of/files/*.tsv` (which exists as a NFS link to a shared file system (which I can confirm to be accessible from all of the other nodes)). However, when using the `--sshloginfile` option to execute remotely on other nodes, see the error

> /bin/bash: line 27: /path/to/a/set/of/files/*.tsv: No such file or directory

as if the function is getting the glob pattern itself as a filename (rather than a filename from a list of files returned by the glob (as it appears to behave when running in single-node mode)).

If anyone knows what's going on here, advice and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the problem was that when using the `-q` option (which was being used in the command to bring in the `"$TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN"` arg into the parallel job without splitting the string variable which had spaces in it). Unquoting the `"$DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB"` glob pattern variable to just be `$DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB` solved the problem.